# Put placeholder using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can put a placeholder through jQuery if there is a single `<input>` on the page:

```js
<input type="text"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
    placeholders();
    function placeholders() {
        $('input[type=text]').each(function() {

            $(this).attr('placeholder', 'hello' );
        });
    }
});
```

However, I have multiple `<input>` fields in a single page as below:

```js
<input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

I wish to add a placeholder only on the first `<input type="text">` that has `class="first"`.

**How can I add a placeholder to the first matching text `input` only?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to add a placeholder only on the first  that
>   has class="first".
>
> How can I add a placeholder to the first matching text input only?

Try using `document.querySelector()` with selector `"input[type=text][class=first]"` , `setAttribute()`

```js
function placeholders() {
  document.querySelector("input[type=text][class=first]")
  .setAttribute("placeholder", "hello");
}

$(document).ready(placeholders);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type=text].first').attr('placeholder', 'hello' );
```

Here `input` will select all the `input tag`, `[type=text]` will select input whose type is text and then `.first` will select a subset with class `first`.

If you want to select the first input with `first` class then do `$('input[type=text].first').first()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=text].first').attr('placeholder', 'hello' );
```

using the [class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:
    `$('input[type=text].first').attr('placeholder', 'hello' );`

Answer (score 0):

if you want an element specific script, use ID instead of CLASS for better performance.

```
<input type="text" class="first" id="first">

$("#first").attr('placeholder', 'hello' );
```